# Python UDP socket errors when sending large packets

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I get an error when dealing with UDP sockets in Python.

I am making an application to send files, and/or folders with many files, over the local network. The user can choose between the TCP and UDP protocols, and it works perfectly with TCP, but not with UDP.

When building the app, I found that it is impossible to send and/or listen for large messages (I don't remember exactly, but I think it's a maximum of 65kb per message).

I decided to split the total bytes into chunks, with an obviously max length of 65k, and send them as different messages in a row.

This solution works fine... but not with very long messages, like big folders with lots of files: the message is received or not at all, it stops at a certain point (I can not assert what point or length exactly, but I think this is important to solve the error), and the server waits forever.

To solve this, I decided to use a simple `time.sleep(0.01)` right after each `sock.sendto(...)` function call in the loop. **This works fine!**

**Is there a way to solve this?**

I think it's a problem with the maximum bytes possible to receive (like the 65kb) on the receiving end, so it listens for the maximum possible and just discards the next messages "in the same second or row", because they are sent too fast.

Comment: Unlike TCP, UDP does not guarantee packets get delivered in order, or even at all. You have to design recovery logic into your transfer protocol.  Like putting a sequence number into the packets, and ACKing the packets you do receive, so the sender can re-send missing packets.  Doing large data transfers with UDP is messy, I suggest you use a pre-existing protocol that is designed to handle this, such as [TFTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1350), etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you. I think I should remove the protocol selection and just use TCP. Other than that... do you think the app is useless or is it a good idea? I want to upload to my repository.

Comment: Why do you want to use UDP at all to transfer massive amounts of data, where data integrity is important? In any case, it is likely that (as you guessed), when sending large messages, you are simply sending data faster than the receiver can read it, so the receiver's internal buffer fills up, discarding messages. That is why slowing down the sender helps. TCP handles traffic control automatically, but you have to handle it manually in UDP.

Comment: You could try implementing some extra messaging in your protocol to have only such much data in flight at a time, requiring ACKs to continue sending. Or, you could try using `socket.setsockopt(SO_RCVBUF)` to increase the size of the receiver's internal buffer so fewer messages get discarded. But ultimately, you can't rely on UDP never losing packets, because it WILL lose packets somtimes. That is just the nature and risk of using UDP.

Comment: You have discovered why people use TCP. It does all this for you. If you make your own version you'll just be reinventing TCP from scratch.